# Subtract minutes from date using strtotime

Tags: php, strtotime

I have the current date format `$date = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm'` and notice that `$date` is already set and not using the `Date` class. I understand I have to use `strtotime` which I have done to my `$date` `$datestr = strtotime($date)`. I wish to subtract 5 minutes to the set time.

I've tried this simple thing `$A = strtotime($date) - strtotime('-5 min');` But it does not aid me.

Comment: Why `strtotime()`? PHP has [`DateTime()`](http://us1.php.net/DateTime) API introduced long ago. `strtotime()` is .. well, old school. (or old skull - take your pick)

Comment: `$A = strtotime('-5 min', strtotime($date));`

Comment: So `$date` is a string and you want directly subtract 5 mins from this string. You can change minute part, but you must consider a lot of case like if minute is bigger than 60, if hour is bigger than 24 and so on. The best case is in my opinion to do calculations on miliseconds and then convert it back to string in your date format

Answer (score 1):

its simple to subtract the `seconds of 5 minutes` which is `(5*60)=300`  from your time

like this

```
$time = strtotime($date);
$time_new = $time-(5*60); // will time of the -5 min from the current $time
```

**example**

```
$date = date('d-M-Y g:i:s A'); // current date
echo $date."<br/>"; // output : 17-Feb-2014 8:35:58 AM
$time = strtotime($date);     // convert current date to timestamp
$time_new = $time - (5*60);   // subtract 5 minutes from current time.
$date_new = date('d-M-Y g:i:s A', $time_new); // convert time to the date again
echo $date_new;  // output : 17-Feb-2014 8:30:58 AM
```